# Deducing an equation for a sine wave from given properties

Tags: trigonometry

Write an equation for a non-piecewise function $f$ with the following properties (where $a$, $m$, and $w$ are arbitrary constants):

- $f$ is a sine wave
- $f(0) = a$ (where $a$ is a value within the range of $f$)
- $f$ has an amplitude of $m$
- $f$'s domain consists of all real numbers
- $f$ touches the x-axis once every $w$ units
- $f$ is never negative

Here's some of the things I've deduced from the facts given:

- $f$ has a period of $w$
- $f$ is translated $m$ units upwards (due to touching but not moving across the x-axis)

Thus, the function so far may look like this:

$$f(x) = msin\left(\frac{wx}{2\pi} \right)+m$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, particularly with the desired intersection of the y-axis. An x translation seems to be necessary but I'm not sure how to figure out the distance that the equation should be "moved".

Also, is there any reliable or consistent process that minimizes guesswork for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general equation is correct - if you add the phase shift ($\theta$):
$$f(x)=m\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{w}x+\theta\right)+m$$
$\theta$ is the phase angle (or time-shift) of the sine wave.
Let's find this parameter, since it is the only unknown one:
$$f(0)=a \rightarrow m\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{w}0+\theta\right)+m=a
\rightarrow \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a-m}{m}\right)=\theta$$
So your final equation should be:
$$f(x)=m\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{w}x+\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a-m}{m}\right)\right)+m$$

Answer (score 1):

The function is actually in the form of $$m\sin \left(\frac{2\pi }{w}\left(x+b\right)\right)+m$$
and if you replace $f(x)$ with $a$ and $x$ with $0$ then you can solve for $b$ which turns out to "be" $$\frac{w}{2\pi }\arcsin \left(\frac{a}{m}-1\right)$$